# is it possible to show a Button only if admin use?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need some help or want to know if it is possible or not ..

I want to show a Button if only the current user has administrator rights.

In my redux state there is a isAdministrator Attribute and if the current user has isAdministrator: true then I want to show the Button.

```
return (
<div>
 {userInfo ? (
        <Link id="OpenUserManagament" to="/userManagement">
        <Button style={{ marginLeft: 10, marginBottom: 6 }} size="lg">
          User Management
        </Button>
      </Link>
        ):(
      <Nav.Link></Nav.Link>
        )}
</div>
)
```

So something after userInfo .. that´s my state Information

```
const userLogin = useSelector((state) => state.userLogin);
  const { userInfo } = userLogin;
```

```
{loading: true, userInfo: {…}}
loading: true
userInfo:
auth: {username: 'admin', password: '********'}
isAdministrator: true
token: {}
userID: "admin"
userName: "admin"
_id: ""
[[Prototype]]: Object
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

Comment: If the `isAdministrator` attribute is on `userInfo`, then maybe `userInfo?.isAdministrator`?

Comment: This is not working .. the error is : TypeError: userInfo?.isAdministrator is not a Function

Comment: That sounds like you added `()` to try to call the boolean.

Comment: How can I call it ?

Comment: You don't need to call it. `{userInfo?.isAdministrator : <>You're an admin</> : <>You're not an admin</>}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple ternary does the trick...

```js
// Just a dummy example...
function AdminButton({ userInfo }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {userInfo.isAdministrator ? (
        <React.Fragment>
          <p>hello admin here&apos;s some links and blah blah blah</p>
          <button onClick={() => alert('yay!!')}>Hello, admin!</button>
        </React.Fragment>
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<AdminButton userInfo={{ isAdministrator: true }} />, root);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<h1>Welcome! If you see a button below, you are the admin</h1>
<div id="root"></div>
```

I just used `null`, which displays nothing if the user isn't a admin for the purpose of the demo. You can display other stuff with something like:

```
(/* ... */) : (
  <Nav.Link></Nav.Link>
)
```

Comment: I did not understand this answer here..

Comment: but there is too much is unnecessary code ... it has to be easier

Comment: @basics_ for one, some code is just for the demo (like the HTML). When people from Stack Overflow answer your question, they expect you to be able to have a basic understanding of the code. Could you tell me which part is unnecessary? (Please keep in mind, the only necessary code would be `{useInfo.isAdministrator ? <p>yes</p> : <p>no</p>}`)

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is possible. But from your code, I can't understand how your userLogin object looks like. You can try to console.log it, so you can see what is in it.

once you solve there you need to wrap your code inside a div like this:

```
//here is component body

return (
    <div>
        {userInfo.userId === "admin" ?? (
        <Link id="OpenUserManagament" to="/userManagement">
        <Button style={{ marginLeft: 10, marginBottom: 6 }} size="lg">
          User Management
        </Button>
      </Link>
        )}
    </div>

)
```

It should work if you can sortout userInfo

Comment: I can show you whats inside userInfo yes

Comment: I edit my answer so you can see it

Comment: just to be sure. if you call this ````{isAdministrator: true
token: {...}
userID: "admin"
userName: "admin"
_id: "..."}```` as userLogin, then instead of userInfo? you can try userLogin.isAdministrator

Comment: userLogin does also not working :)

Comment: or if you call it as userInfo then userInfo.isAdministrator ?

Comment: I do this too .. but that´s also not working .. -.-

Comment: Do you get any error? also to be sure, check if there is any typo like userlogin userLogin  or something like that. Did you console log your userInfo object?

Comment: Yeah I have edit it to my answer that´s the console log

Comment: I have add some more console log

Comment: I updated the answer just a bit. if above option doesn't work, console.log(userInfo.userId). if result is not "admin", it means there is something wrong about how you call object or object keys. if result is "admin", then there can be many reasons why your button doesn't show and I can't really say where the problem is with very limited information

Comment: Deniz this will maybe work but there is not one admin with admin rights it could be another user .. so isAdministrator would be nice but it doesn´t work -.-